# MYSQL ORDER BY CASE WHEN not working properly

Tags: mysql, case, sql-order-by

MB_KOM are first locations returned from this query, then MLL,MDL...etc.

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(location, 7, 20) AS ExtractString FROM inventory
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN location LIKE "MB_BN%" THEN location END ASC,
        CASE
        WHEN location LIKE "MB_B%" THEN location END ASC,
        CASE
        WHEN location LIKE "MB_KOM%" THEN ExtractString+0 END DESC
```

So what am i missing here?

Edit:
Goal is to get locations in this order:
MB_BN% ASC,
MB_B% ASC,
MB_KOM% DESC,
THEN anything else...

After MB_BN and MB_B and MB_KOM are always some numbers.
Example: MB_KOM199, MB_BN010406, MB_B12

Comment: You do not explain how the resultset should be ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ORDER BY` with three expressions, so it sorts by the first expression alone, unless that results in a tie. Then it resolves the tie by the second expression. And so on.

Did you mean to use a single `CASE` expression with multiple cases?

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN location LIKE 'MB_BN%' THEN location
    WHEN location LIKE 'MB_B%' THEN location
    WHEN location LIKE 'MB_KOM%' THEN ExtractString+0 END
```

But that has a few problems:

- You can't mix `ASC` and `DESC` sort order in the same ORDER BY argument.
- You can't mix sorting alphabetically and numerically in the same ORDER BY argument. Even though you used the `+0` trick to cast the ExtractString to an numeric, it will be cast back to string to be compatible with the expression.
- The `CASE` has no `ELSE`, so if the location matches none of the patterns, the result of the expression is NULL, and the sorting will be in some arbitrary order.

Here's a different solution:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN location LIKE 'MB_BN%' THEN 1 
       WHEN location LIKE 'MB_B%' THEN 2 
       WHEN location LIKE 'MB_KOM%' THEN 3 
      ELSE 4 END AS location_type,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(location, '[[:digit:]]+') AS digits
FROM inventory
ORDER BY location_type ASC,  
  (CASE location_type WHEN 3 THEN -digits ELSE digits END)+0 ASC;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q0y95acw)

Comment: Question is edited now with more information about sort...
Solution with bigint is close but it returns MB_B first then MB_BN and MB_KOM.

Comment: See my edited solution and dbfiddle demonstration.